# R: Line chart How to display x-value as year and month in proper sequence?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, plotly, flexdashboard

I want to plot the line chart by number of orders_due to which user monthly.
Need Displayed month_year should be in sequence.

Data set like

```
User            Due_date 
a               02-10-2017
b               02-02-2017
a               02-08-2017
c               02-08-2017
a               02-08-2017
s               02-06-2017
c               02-06-2017
s               02-06-2017
b               02-06-2017
c               02-11-2017
a               02-11-2017
s               02-11-2017
c               02-01-2017
s               02-01-2017
b               02-01-2017
b               02-10-2017
```

I am try to generate it but month order not getting correct.

```
inv$Month_Due <- inv$Due_Date
day(inv$Month_Due) <- days_in_month(inv$Due.Date)

inv<-inv[order(as.Date(inv$Due_Date, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
inv$start_year_month <- format(inv$Month_Due, "%Y-%B")


#Chart generate
rpivotTable(inv,  aggregatorName = "Count as Fraction of Total",  rows = "User",  cols = c("start_year_month"),  width = "100%",  height = "200px",rendererName = "Line Chart")
```

Report displayed result as:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your variable `start_year_month` is a character string (or factor) and sorted alphabetically.

After calling

```
inv$start_year_month <- format(inv$Month_Due, "%Y-%B")
```

R doesn't "know "anymore" that `start_year_month` encodes data.time information and uses the variable as if it was a string (= alphabetic sorting).

You can either:

1.(Better solution) leave it as a data.time column and use that for plotting

or

2.Make it to a ordered factor, by using the parameter `levels` and passing it a vector with all unique values for `start_year_month` in the correct order. I.e.

```
inv$start_year_month <- factor(inv$start_year_month, levels=paste(unique(format(inv$Month_Due, "%Y")), month.name, sep="-"))
```